# How to show $\sigma(\Delta)\le 0$ in $L^2(R^2,dxdy)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$\Delta=\partial_{xx}+\partial_{yy}$. $\sigma(\Delta)$ is the spectrum of $\Delta$ acting in $L^2(R^2,dxdy)$.How to show $\sigma(\Delta)\le 0$ and the bound is sharp?